# Can row be hilighted when each cell in the row has differing colors or CSS values?

Tags: css, gridview, hover, row, cells

Is it possible to use CSS hover to hilight a row in a GridView when row is composed of cells with differing CSS values for background, foreground colors, border values, etc.?
When the row has cells that don't have this variation in style, the row hilights fine, it's only when each row has each cells specified with different CSS values that the row is not hilighted.  I'm not sure why since the row and cell are differnt html elements.

Comment: There are no "row" or "cell" HTML Elements. There are "tr", "th" and "td". The "th" and "td" may be considered "cells". Your markup and CSS would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If each cell has a different color, highlight the cells on row hover and not the row.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MPxNc/